# HighCharts: Reduce size of chart

Tags: highcharts, lazy-high-charts

Does anyone know how to reduce the size of this pie chart? I am using Lazy High Charts gem.

```
return LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('pie') do |f|
      f.chart({:defaultSeriesType=>"pie" , :margin=> [0, 0, 0, 0],  backgroundColor: "#F5F5F5", renderTo: "mediamix#{akid.to_s}"} )
      f.series({:type=> 'pie', :name=> "Count",:data=> data_val, borderWidth: 0})
      f.title({ :text=> nil})
      f.plot_options({:pie=>{:allowPointSelect=>true, :cursor=>"pointer" , dataLabels: {enabled: true}, showInLegend: false}})
    end
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Highcharts renders the charts to fill the containing div that you specify in the renderTo option. In your case, you are specifying:

```
renderTo:"mediamix#{akid.to_s}"
```

I don't use Lazy Highcharts Gem, so I don't know what this refers to, but you need to look through your code for where this div is defined, and set it's height and width to the size you need.

Comment: I am generating the DIV ID dynamically as you can see (mediamix#{akid.to_s}) ... hence I cannot style this unknown ID from stylesheet. The ID is being used within the high_chart command = high_chart("mediamix#{f.id.to_s}", Gakie.pie(f.id))

Comment: You have to give the div a size somehow. Either give it a class, set it's height/width properties, or amend it's size using javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 6):

You can also explitly define the width and height via Highchart API:

```
 $('#container').highcharts({
       chart: {
                height: 200,
               width:100
            });
```